# Sublime Text 3 - Japanese IME input not working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, ime

I've set the japanese IME in my Keyboard settings on windows 7. With alt+shift it works well with the built-in text editor, but nothing happens in sublime text 3.
I then installed google's japanese ime and even though the input changed visually (know shows the window with the japanese characters when typing in text editor) still nothing happens in sublime text 3.

I see no window for typing, nor do the characters change into hiragana (japanese symbols).

I tried installing the IMESupport plugin, but that didn't solve the problem.

If I switch between the 2 keyboard settings and switch on and off the japanese ime it still never works with sublime text 3, I've searched for answers but haven't found one that would've worked yet.

Answer (score 4):

As your question title does not specify windows, search results will end up here for Linux and Mac also. I apologize that I can't help you with Windows, but for googlers who end up here, on Linux it's possible to input Japanese text if you follow the instructions at the links below.

http://futago-life.com/sublime-text3-wiki/first-step/japanese/linux

https://github.com/yasuyuky/SublimeMozcInput

Altough it's mentioned in the links above, you need to visit the package control installer listed below if you don't use it already. I'm assuming this is platform transparent and you may just find a work around for windows if you fine tune your search with a focus on Mozc.

http://packagecontrol.io/installation

5 minute easy install!

I can at last get some work done.

Comment: **From yasuyuky's github**

This is Sublime Text 2/3 Plugin for Using Mozc(mozc_server) via mozc_emacs_helper

Though this plugin is intended to be used on Linux, it may work on the other platforms.

This plugin is tested on Mac OSX (10.7), Ubuntu12.04 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Install *ibus-mozc* and *emacs-mozc*:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ibus-mozc emacs-mozc
```

In Sublime, open Command Palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Package Control: Add Repository 
-> https://github.com/yasuyuky/SublimeMozcInput

Package Control: Install Package
-> SublimeMozcInput

Restart Sublime.

Toggle Japanese Input in Sublime <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>